# Statistics Question regarding Probability

Tags: probability

I have been trying to solve this problem, but I don't know where to start.
Can someone help me? Thank you.

A biometric security device using fingerprints erroneously refuses to admit 3 in 1,500 authorized persons from a facility containing classified information. The device will erroneously admit 3 in 1,005,000 unauthorized persons. Assume that 98 percent of those who seek access are authorized.

If the alarm goes off and a person is refused admission, what is the probability that the person was really authorized?

Comment: Have you tried using Bayes' Theorem/Tree diagram or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Bayes theorem, $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}$ and the law of total probability, $P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n{P(A|B_i)P(B_i)}$ for a set of states $B_i$ which partitions the state space. $(i \in {1,...,n}) $

From the question, let $R$ be the event an individual was refused entry, and $A$ be the event an individual was authorised.

> refuses to admit 3 in 1,500 authorised persons

From this, we have $P(R|A) = \frac{3}{1,500}$

> erroneously admit 3 in 1,005,000 unauthorised persons

From this we have $P(R^c|A^c) = \frac{3}{1,005,000}$

> 98 percent of those who seek access are authorised

$P(A) = 0.98$

We are asked to calculate the probability $P(A|R)$

We know, from Bayes theorem, that $P(A|R) = \frac{P(R|A)P(A)}{P(R)}$

Which means all we need to know is $P(R)$

Given that the events $R$ and $R^c$, as well as $A$ and $A^c$ partition the state space, can use the law of total probability to find $P(R)$

$1 - P(R^c|A^c) = P(R|A^c)$

Therefore,

$P(R) = (1 - P(R^c|A^c)) (1-P(A)) + P(R|A)P(A)$

$P(R) = P(R|A^c)P(A^c) + P(R|A)P(A)$

By using this resultant value of $P(R)$ in the equation

$P(A|R) = \frac{P(R|A)P(A)}{P(R)}$

We have our solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to think of these problems using trees. However, I will go about this by using Bayes Theorem.

Reminder: Bayes Theorem states that $P(A | B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Let $B$ be the even that the alarm went off, and $A$ the event that the person was really authorized. Then, in order to calculate $P(A|B)$, we need to know $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(B)$. We know that the device erroneously refuses to admit $3/1500$ people, and so we have $P(A \cap B) = (0.98)\frac{3}{1500}$. $P(B)$ in this case would be the probability that someone caused the alarm to go off -- so we have $(0.98)(3/1500)+(0.02)(1,004,997/1005000)$. Then you just combine these together like the Theorem states -- so we have $P(A | B) = \frac{(0.98)(\frac{3}{1500})}{(0.98)(3/1500)+(0.02)(1,004,997/1005000)} = \frac{4690}{52547} \approx 0.089$.